# How to request Moderator elections in a Beta site?

Tags: support

The Project Management SE is well populated and considered useful to those of us that frequent it but the moderation is sparse and we have had examples recently of [rollback wars](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/786) and threads from lack of Moderator oversight.

How can we increase the amount of Mods and force an election to supplement the current moderators on the site since many of the power users from the past hardly frequent the site any more.

I don't want to be a Mod myself particularly but I can think of several who would be well suited to do so.

Comment: I think that this is something that you should bring up on [meta.pm.stackexchange.com].  If your pro tempore moderators need help, are jaded or otherwise think a change in the site's moderators would assist the site then they can always contact SE staff to alter their moderator team.

Comment: My point is that those Moderators are there infrequently, how can we rectify that issue with absentee mods?

Comment: The best way to find out if your moderators can help is to ask them.  As soon as you post on your Meta they get a message to their Moderator Inbox.  Without asking how do you know that the moderators are absent?  Is there a single post on your Meta that has highlighted the issue that you are bringing here?

Comment: Yes.  http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/a/788/10462

Comment: I think you should make a specific post on http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com to ask whether any of the current moderators are interested in requesting a change to their moderator complement, citing your reason(s) for asking.  If you get no response within a couple of working days then I think you would have a case to [contact Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).

Comment: It is good that you have posted http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/questions/789 but I think you have partially ignored my advice.  I would not expect there to be any option for moderator elections on a beta site but I think that if you ask the pro tempore (appointed) moderators there whether they need help then you are far more likely to progress this.

Comment: Sorry - I def misunderstood you.